# why we cannot intialize with vector size in class in c++

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, size

why we cannot intialize with vector size in class in c++?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class s{
    public:
       vector<int> arr(4);
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    int n = 10;
    std::vector<int> arr(n);

    return 0;
}
```

in this code i have intialize arr with 4 size but it showing error

we can intialize vector with size but  why we cannot intialize

why it showing error:

```
main.cpp:15:24: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   15 |        vector<int> arr(4);
      |                        ^
main.cpp:15:24: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

Comment: As default initializer list, try with `vector<int> arr{4};` or `vector<int> arr = vector<int>(4);`.

Comment: Side notes: (1) [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Initializing the size should be done in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: The reason is you can only have `brace-or-equal-initializers` in your class/struct declaration. You are trying to use a constructor

Comment: For historical reasons (i.e. C), everything that has the form `Type name(parameters)` and is inside a class definition is a member function declaration.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wouldn't consider the use of default initializers for member variables/implicitly generated&defaulted default constructors bad practice in any way. Following your advice would make the use of those impossible in many circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

C++ treats your "initialization" as a declaration of a function called `arr` and returning a `vector<int>`, so it expects a parameter declarator instead of 4.

clang gives a better(?) error message(using godbolt):

```
<source>:7:24: error: expected parameter declarator
       vector<int> arr(4);
                       ^
```

Solution: <del>Use {} instead of ().</del> Use assignment if you want a vector of 4 items, or use {} if you want a vector with a single 4.

Comment: Unfortunately using `{4}` gives you a vector with a single element (value 4), not a vector of size 4.